# Python: Problem importing pycurl

Tags: python

I am working on OpenSolaris(2009.06) OS. i recently installed the pycurl libraires using the following command:

```
$> python setup.py install --curl-config=/usr/local/bin/curl-config
```

the installation went perfectly fine. However now when i am trying to import the pycurl library in my python program, an error is being reported

```
>>>import pycurl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
ImportError: ld.so.1: isapython2.4: fatal: libcurl.so.4: open failed: No such file or directory
```

I cant figure out where exactly i am going wrong. Any help...?

Thanks in advance.
Shubham

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your loader doesn't know where to find the cURL library. See your OS documentation for how to specify locations to search.

Comment: The cURL library is installed in the /usr/bin directory

$> which curl
/usr/bin/curl

and the PATH variable has the entry for this directory :

$> echo $PATH
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

is this not sufficient???

Comment: Uh... that's the binary. It's looking for the library.